# Generate function definition with template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

How to write a template Haskell function such that:

```
mkFunc "func"
```

generates

```
func = "func"
```

I've tried this

```
mkFunc x = ValD (VarP x) (NormalB (LitE (StringL x))) []
```

But it doesn't typecheck:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Name’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: String
  Actual type: Name
In the first argument of ‘StringL’, namely ‘x’
In the first argument of ‘LitE’, namely ‘(StringL x)’
```

Also, after defining `mkFunc`, how can I define `mkFuncs` which makes a list of function definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get help using `runQ` and see what abstract syntax tree it produces:

```
λ> runQ [d|func = "func"|]
[ValD (VarP func_4) (NormalB (LitE (StringL "func"))) []]
```

And then you can just translate that into code:

```
-- External.hs
{-#LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell#-}

module External where

import Language.Haskell.TH

mkFunc :: String -> Q [Dec]
mkFunc str = return [ValD (VarP str') (NormalB (LitE (StringL str))) []]
    where str' = mkName str
```

And the other module:

```
-- Other.hs
{-#LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell#-}
import External

$(mkFunc "haskell")

main = print haskell
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> main
"haskell"
```

And creating `mkFuncs` is straightforward from this:

```
mkFuncs :: [String] -> Q [Dec]
mkFuncs srt = return decs
    where dec n s = ValD (VarP n) (NormalB (LitE (StringL s))) []
          srt' = map (\x -> (mkName x, x)) srt
          decs = map (\(n,s) -> dec n s) srt'
```

Comment: thanks! a little more refined: makeFuncs::[String]->Q [Dec]
makeFuncs ss=return $ foldl1 (++) $ mapM (\x->[ValD (VarP (mkName x)) (NormalB (LitE (StringL x))) []]) ss         btw, can we use quasiquoters instead of manipulating AST directly?